# Circular dependency of knockout computed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

see working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ruslans/vFK82/

I have 3 fields: Net Price (ex. tax), tax amount and Total price (price ex. vat + tax amount).
the NetPrice and the Total are writable, i.e. you can change either of them and the other 2 values must be auto-calculated.

The way I've done it is using 3 observable and 2 computed knockout objects but I thought perhaps someone who knows Knockout a lot better could suggest a more efficient way to achieve this.

html:

```
Net Price:
<input type="textbox" data-bind="value: NetPriceCalc" />
<br />Tax Amount:
<label data-bind="html: TaxAmt"></label>
<br />Total:
<input type="textbox" data-bind="value: TotalCalc" />
```

script:

```
var viewModel = {
    NetPrice: ko.observable(100),
    TaxAmt: ko.observable(20),
    Total: ko.observable(120),
    TaxRate: 0.2
};

viewModel.updateTaxAmt = function (useNetPrice) {
    if (useNetPrice) {
        return this.TaxAmt(this.NetPrice() * this.TaxRate);
    } else {
        var total = Number(this.Total());
        var taxAmt = total - total / (1 + this.TaxRate);
        return this.TaxAmt(taxAmt);
    }
};
viewModel.updateNetPrice = function () {
    this.NetPrice(Number(this.Total()) - Number(this.TaxAmt()));
};
viewModel.updateTotal = function () {
    this.Total(Number(this.NetPrice()) + Number(this.TaxAmt()));
};

viewModel.NetPriceCalc = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        console.log("NetPriceCalc read");
        return viewModel.NetPrice();
    },
    write: function (value) {
        console.log("NetPriceCalc write");
        viewModel.NetPrice(value);
        viewModel.updateTaxAmt(true);
        return viewModel.updateTotal();
    }
});
viewModel.TotalCalc = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        console.log("TotalCalc read");
        return viewModel.Total();
    },
    write: function (value) {
        console.log("TotalCalc write");
        viewModel.Total(value);
        viewModel.updateTaxAmt(false);
        return viewModel.updateNetPrice();
    }
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly better and efficient way could be this :

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vFK82/4/)

*Html*

```
Net Price:
<input type="textbox" data-bind="value: NetPrice" />
<br />Tax Amount:
<label data-bind="html: TaxAmt"></label>
<br />Total:
<input type="textbox" data-bind="value: Total" />
```

*JS*

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.NetPrice = ko.observable(100);

    self.TaxRate = 0.2;

    self.TaxAmt = ko.computed(function() {
        return parseFloat(self.NetPrice()) * self.TaxRate;
    });

    self.Total = ko.computed({
        read: function() { 
               return parseFloat(self.NetPrice()) + self.TaxAmt();
        },
        write: function(val){
                var total = parseFloat(val);
                var taxAmt = total - total / (1 + self.TaxRate);     
                self.NetPrice(total - taxAmt);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Pretty cool. You can add `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` to the data-bind attribute of the fields so that they update on every key stroke.

Answer (score 6):

Some comments to the OP:

- You don't need the `return` clause in the `write` method of the `ko.computed`.
- Your approach uses the `Number()` function on several places and you might like to change that in order to get an specific precision (or some centralized place for validation of user input). So you can use [ko.extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) to improve that. And I would specifically recommend the extender already made by the ko team named [`ko.extenders.numeric`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html#live_example_1_forcing_input_to_be_numeric).
- Your approach also uses `console.log()` on several places, and you might want to use another ko.extender made by the ko team [`ko.extenders.logChange`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html#how_to_create_an_extender).
- Instead of a `ko.computed` in this case I think it's better to use [`subscribe`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables) as it will take less code (and probably insignificantly faster).

My approach would be this:

```
function viewModel() {
    this.TaxRate = 0.2;
    this.NetPrice = ko.observable().extend({ numeric: 2, logChange: "NetPrice"  });
    this.TaxAmt = ko.observable().extend({ numeric: 2, logChange: "TaxAmt"  });
    this.Total = ko.observable().extend({ numeric: 2, logChange: "Total"  });

    this.NetPrice.subscribe(function (newNetPrice) {
        this.TaxAmt(newNetPrice * this.TaxRate);
        this.Total(newNetPrice + this.TaxAmt());
    }, this);
    this.Total.subscribe(function (newTotal) {
        this.TaxAmt(newTotal - newTotal / (1 + this.TaxRate));
        this.NetPrice(newTotal - this.TaxAmt());
    }, this);

    this.NetPrice(100);
}

// then I have the extenders code copied exactly as seen in: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html)
ko.extenders.numeric = ...
ko.extenders.logChange = ... 

// and finally init everything as usual
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

You can see the working fiddle here: **http://jsfiddle.net/protron/JFPgu/2/**

Note how the numbers in this solution never have more decimals than the specified on the numeric extenders (even the value entered by the user is automatically fixed to the desired precision).

And comparing my answer to the currently accepted answer by gaurav (which is also pretty nice and simple): I think the main advantage of my approach is that it'll let you use these awesome extenders.

Comment: Ooh, `extenders` are pretty cool, especially the fact that I can add sub-observables to existing observables - my use case is error messages about specific pieces of rendered UI, coming in from a different endpoint (not my choice of API architecture).

Answer (score 0):

Can't promise this will fix the problem, but sometimes enabling deferred updates can fix problems like this.

It's a good feature to be aware of, but be cautious about enabling it for an already working application - and also if you do have an underlying problem then you'll still want to fix that.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html

Comment: Note: This is NOT the same as a deferred observable - and is a new feature from 3.4.0 onwards